# Can we set user settings while installing Android app

Tags: android

Can we set user settings while installing Android app ?

Ex : set domain name or login credentials used by service that starts on boot up.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "user settings". It depends on what they are, where you're storing them and how they're accessed. But you can't do anything with your app while it's installing off the `Google Play marketplace`

Comment: Maybe not the best phrased question, but if you mean set things like the contents of `SharedPreferences` or a sqlite3 database, I'd also be interested in knowing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

not while installing it, as far as I know, no code in your app runs during install.  Not until the device user elects to open your app.

If you're adjusting settings based on the device configuration, then you can adjust values with the device config resources (values-XX resource folders) because those strings will get mapped in the manifest.xml but it doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run any code during the installation of an app. If you would like to run some code the first time an app is run, you can use `SharedPreferences` and put a `Boolean isRunningForTheFirstTime` variable in there. Set it to `true` by `default` and once the code that you needed to run has been executed, just change the value to `false`. Make sure, if you use this method, to `commit` the changes to the `SharedPreferences.editor`. Hope this helps.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html